# Ping.fm tagging on Tumblr/ add tags to each post?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-tags

I recently tried out the ping.fm tagging feature, which doesn't seem to work as planned.

No matter if posted to Blogspot or Tumblr, the Tags never show up  -  the are appended as static text, not as tags.

So, is there any way to actually get the @tags working, or edit a tumblr blog theme in a way that it always appends a specific tag automatically?

Comment: Ping.fm is dead. Should this question can be removed?
Or shall I just point to http://composer.io, a replacement for ping.fm?

Comment: Ping.fm is no more.

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering, but are you being sure you're using `@t` and then the tags and not `@tags`? Because the latter is incorrect.

From [Ping.fm's help & info wiki](http://pingfm.pbworks.com/w/page/16881276/Posting-Tags)

> **@t tags.**  You can append your message with **"@t"** then list tags (comma separated).  These will be appended as hashtags on networks that support hashtagging, or as tags on networks that support tagging.  The tags used with **@t** will not be displayed on any other networks.
>
> **Example:** Posting *"I am posting tags to Ping.fm @t posting, tags"* would tell Ping.fm to take the words after the **"@t"** delimiter and post them throughout your networks.  Again, for sites like Twitter that support hashtagging, the tags you include will be superimposed in the message you post.  So, posting this message would show up like *"I am #posting #tags to Ping.fm"* on Twitter et. al and for the other sites it would show up like *"I am posting tags to Ping.fm"* and the supplied tags would be included wherever they are posted normally.

Comment: Ping.fm no longer exists.

Comment: Al E. is correct... however, at the time of this answer, Ping.fm _was_ still in existence.